# Timeout error on MariaDB in Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, ufw

I have an ArchLinux installation with Docker and [MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) running in a container.

Now when I try to connect to the database, I get the following euro: `MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '$mydomain' (4)`.

Things I did to make it available:

- Created root-user and granted `%` access.
- Mounted folder with `custom.cnf` with following contents:

  ```
  [mysqld]
  bind-address=0.0.0.0
  ```
- Exposed `3306:3306` in `docker run`
- Configured UFW `ufw status | grep 3306`:

  ```
  3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
  3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
  ```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I can connect with the given password from within the container, but not from my local host.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I managed to connect from another container via the internal ip of the container, so it works on the host I think? Maybe it's a firewall issue (but that doesn't make sense since disabling ufw and iptables does not help anything).

Comment: What is `$mydomain` supposed to be?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The domain of the server I'm connecting to from my local computer. The server is running docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Docker issue, adding `--net=host` to `docker run` fixes it. See [#13914](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13914) for more information.

Comment: What to do incase of docker compose

Comment: Is there a way to add this to a container post-creation?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using docker compose you can add this to the docker-compose.yml file to see if the issue is still there.

network_mode: "host"

Answer (score 0):

This solution is much better and has no security issues: https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/113#issuecomment-380868523

```
       command: [
            '--wait_timeout=28800',
        ]
```